# General term for permanent or non-permanent

Tags: single-word-requests, generic-term, category

As the title states. I'm looking for a general term for permanent, temporary, etc. The best I could come up with so far is permanence, although after I looked at the definition I'm not sure that really makes sense.

Comment: _Longevity_ and _durability_, like _permanence_, default to the 'long-lastingness' sense. However, [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/durability) gives the example 'One way of measuring the durability of an airplane is to check how many of those built are still flying' which displays the '**how** long-lasting?' sense

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Agreed, I like persistence too as it has a similar connotation - maybe these kind of terms are the best that can be done :)

Comment: Perhaps _[projected] lifespan_ is broadened enough for most purposes?

Answer (score 1):

A general term (which doesn't imply either side of the scale) is [**duration**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/duration):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **2** : the time during which something exists or lasts
> // were there for the *duration* of the concert

An example sentence more suited to the question is the following:

> Does it have a temporary or permanent *duration*?

In a form, *duration* could also be filled in with a particular time period.